# Is there a better way to run a randomly chosen function?

Tags: python, function, eval

I made a Tic-Tac-Toe game, and for one of the AI's I made, it chooses a random function enclosed in quotes (so it is a string) and calls `eval()` on it. Here's what it look like:

```
import random

func_list = ["func1()", "func2()", "func3()"]

eval(random.choice(func_list))
```

I don't really like using `eval()` (not really sure why, just doesn't seem right). I don't like having to put the functions in the list as strings either. **Is there a better way of doing this?**

Comment: [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." I think you can infer from our common answers that this is one of those situations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functions are first-class objects in Python. That means you can pass them around, and store them in lists as well, just like any other object.

So why not just do this?

```
func_list = [func1, func2, func3]
random.choice(func_list)()
```

Answer (score 4):

Skip the eval and store your functions directly:

```
import random

func_list = [func1, func2, func3]

random.choice(func_list)()
```

Comment: LOL. There was a thundering herd of answers with identical syntax. If you're going to accept one of our shared answers, choose someone with a newer account than me, would you? Share the love with our new friends. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Python functions are objects and you can store references to them. You can then call them using the reference, as long as they can all handle the same argument list.

```
import random

def revlist(mylist):
    return mylist[::-1]

func_list = [list, set, tuple, revlist]

f = random.choice(func_list)

x = f([1,2,3,4,5,1])
print x
```

Each time you execute this, you'll get either a `list`, `set`, `tuple` or a list in reverse at random.

Answer (score 3):

```
func_list = [func1, func2, func3]

random.choice(func_list)()
```

You can put functions in lists directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `locals` to access the randomly chosen function -

```
locals()[random.choice(func_list)]()
```

`locals` works if the function is in the same module.

If the function that you're calling is from another module, you can also use `getattr`

```
import module_name
getattr(module_name, random.choice(func_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions are first level objects. Just put the function in the list and call it directly.

```
def a(): pass
def b(): pass

funcs = [a,b]

# call function 'a'
funcs[0]()
```